# How to activate the camera without presenting any controller?

Tags: ios, swift

**Objective**

I need my app to keep checking if the user is smiling or not, but I should present no `UIImagePickerController`. Using it would be disruptive for my app. My app involves a `UILabel` that tells the user to smile, and should wait for the user to do so.

**Code**

This code checks if the user is smiling or not. It doesn't, however, do anything apart from that. I am looking to add a source of images/videos in order to achieve my objective.

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

func smileDetection() {

    for r in results {
        let face:CIFaceFeature = r as! CIFaceFeature;
        if face.hasSmile {
            println("You are smiling!")
        } else {
            println("You are not smiling!")
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

However, is there any way I can take photos/record videos/activate the camera without presenting any controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just send the camera view to the background behind another view for a quick solution.

You can simply add another view in front of your presented view or send it to the back.

```
view.bringSubviewToFront(blockerView)
```

or

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(cameraView)
```

Based on your comment you're looking to use AVFoundation and CIFaceFeature. Check out [this tut](http://www.icapps.com/face-detection-with-core-image-on-live-video/) to see how to utilize an AVCaptureDevice to grab the image then use the result for CIFaceFeature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a great idea! What camera view should I exactly present? I doubt the  `UIImagePickerController ` used to take photos or videos would be useful because my app should not require the users' input. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and edits. My doubts are cleared now. Thanks again!